# Can a PWM source be used to drive an LC circuit to get it to resonate?

Tags: capacitor, rf, inductor, resonance

I clearly have some uncertainties in understanding how LC circuits work and how they can be used.
I’m interested in rf and came across the topic of LC tank circuits. I am to understand that for an LC circuit to resonate it needs an AC source (basically).
If I were to use a 9v battery for an LC circuit, would PWM be suitable to give the LC circuit the feedback it needs to continuously resonate?

Comment: Google "class E amplifier".

Comment: I will, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Pulse width modulation is a little over the top. Just a plain ordinary pulse at the right pulse repetition frequency is enough to keep an LC circuit topped-up with energy and keep the voltage/current sinewave amplitude at the desired amount.

If the losses in the LC circuit were variable, then, to keep amplitude stability on the sinewave, you might choose to modulate the pulse width.

> *If I were to use a 9v battery for an LC circuit, would PWM be suitable
> to give the LC circuit the feedback it needs to continuously resonate?*

Yes, you could do it that way and monitor amplitude output and make duty cycle modifications and repetition rate modifications as needed or, more simply, build the LC into an oscillator circuit with amplitude stabilization. Frequency stabilization comes free in this alternative example.

Pulse example: -

[image]

As you can see, with a fixed input pulse width, the sinewave output amplitude will continue to grow until the LC losses balance the energy input per cycle so, it can be a little hit and miss deciding what pulse width is necessary. If I put 1 Ω in series with the 1 mH inductor and increase the drive level to the transistor's base a tad, we can see that amplitude stabilizes at about 2 volts p-p: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information! I guess I was under the impression that PWM was the same thing as a send a pulse at a repetitive interval. As if they were interchangeable. 
What then do you suggest I could use to achieve a simple, repetitive pulse?

Comment: Build a square wave oscillator (a relaxation oscillator for instance). Then AND the output with a slightly delayed and inverted version of the output to get a thin sub 10 nano second to 100 ns pulse. You can use RC time constants to vary the pulse width up and down to suit what you need. Or, use a PWM generated pulse as you originally suggested. I would definitely what to simulate first so you have decent ballpark values for any build. My sim is microcap and is free and also free is LTSpice but I don't like LTSpice.

Answer (score 2):

A bandpass filter LC tank filter in an open collector (current sink) will resonate as long as you have sufficient positive feedback gain > 1.  You don't control f with PWM except in special cases. You can control the average DC of a square wave with PWM though and generate more harmonics.

Here the small C's coupled to the emitter drop Vbe which drops Ic which is enough to inject more harmonic energy into the LC BPF to keep oscillating. due to the BPF properties of high Q LC.  (Q=100 max typ)  But realize the Q's of crystals are Q >= 10,000 and are much more stable than LC components.

### When you add positive feedback with Capacitance, then you get self-triggered pulses of current and a famous old transistor [oscillator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCAcB0CsCmBaAjMkBmSAmaB2AbFrNsgCzoCcFY%20pI%20EysIs6LSqAUAO4iK0gskSBiyDh4TgCc%20AoSP5106fOBDJIYLZwAuspStEZDjPsmiRqYUpAI1SFcljZg4m9E0xgVuMBvVaIAAm8ABmAIYArgA2OjxG8lAQiWCcAOZGmEpipIEQqQBKCbhi6GJYuWoQlRRV4HCcAMZJ4iKaovmCcBxo%20NBYVFhCYLD4kOis9VrInADy6kId6gRL%20dILIonIi2WdyFoHqbxlS%2027kselsKWlY%20qc0QkSJ%20f50Idorn5gFJDIjgxcLl0KRSCULi1ztsRK94u0tosUpxgWZtuoGOjkhU1JAAPr7Cq4sC4mz4fD44muZC4lD49YvO4vSB0RiadaKYyqDlZNQabTNM7XSHMtQ4BAoT79ISEChA2j4DzMyXTOEQCY3DBCo7C7IYEXapl0bn6pqQrAQQViZIccrQMHeWhkfbIWiwEZTPz08rgk4pe4ABw2S2hmrEaBZnAA9upw7zyPhkLgPX4pkxzZB5aN7bhiFbBDGMFGCyyFrBYHQYBm-LlSLBcNh8KwXO9pryizkQHRkOgRiJXAngS6bFh9sRmF9W4xOEA).
Notice the bottom trace is Vbe with the disturbance which changes the DC bias current quickly. The Rb and  hFE forces the DC drain current here of 1.3 mA
[image]
The Collector is lightly loaded to rise from start to almost 2x Vbat pp.
other

If you have a high Q Band Pass Filter (BPF) if you pulse it with fast enough risetime and a pulse much shorter than the cycle time, often enough to prevent the decay  of the high Q ringing , then you can make a harmonic-locked-oscillator if you choose the harmonic of your stable pulse rate. to fit inside the BW of your BPF.

[image]
Notice above the first null in harmonics comes from the inverse duty factor or the sine wave that fits in the pulse.  The above shows the (almost) null for a ~5% d.f. and the other harmonics follow an elliptical amplitude pattern. (Recall an infinite narrow impulse would present a flat infinite bandwidth)

If the pulse width is not a very small fraction then when the driver is low impedance and then high impedance when ringing, then the pulse start-stop modulates the amplitude of the carrier depending on the phase of start-stop. But if it is < 1% it can be pretty constant. The DC component changes with duty factor (d.f.)

Another application is the Class D amplifier which use RF pulses to change the DC component with d.f.  then uses a speaker R-damped LC Low Pass  Filter (LPF) to suppress the RF pulse power amp carrier to recover the audio power output .

Yet again other applications include the nonlinear effect of saturation or switching to mix two frequencies and the sum or difference goes in to a BPF to create the Intermediate Frequency with the same carrier modulation.