# Question - LC Tank - Resonance , Duty Cycle , Back EMF

Tags: inductance, resonance, oscillation, duty-cycle, back-emf

I was wondering about that for some time now but didn't have the time to try it myself , maybe some of you guys will help me out with this question :

What happens when LC Tank is operated in its resonance frequency but the duty cycle varies - will it continue to oscillate perfectly (for me - ringing is also called "oscillating perfectly" as long as it is a sine wave) ?

Also , what happens to the back emf at resonance ?
and - what happens to the back emf when ringing occurs at resonance ?

Comment: Look at a class C RF amplifier! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_amplifier_classes#Class_C

Answer (score 2):

> *What happens when LC Tank is operated in its resonance frequency but
> the duty cycle varies - will it continue to oscillate perfectly (for
> me - ringing is also called "oscillating perfectly" as long as it is a
> sine wave) ?*

If you use a parallel LC circuit pulsed via a transistor then the output will look pretty good except where the pulse occurs. At this point, there will be a slight disturbance in the sinewave that may or may not be acceptable. I'm thinking of this type of circuit: -

[image]

This image was taken from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/627863/can-a-pwm-source-be-used-to-drive-an-lc-circuit-to-get-it-to-resonate/627865#627865) and shows a transistor driving an LC circuit. The transistor is fed from a 40 ns pulse that is synchronous with the tuned frequency. The sinewave amplitude is ascending with time and will only settle down to a steady amplitude once the energy fed from the pulse matches the energy lost due to dissipative components in the LC (losses): -

[image]

This image above shows the sinewave settling down to constant amplitude when a 1 Ω resistor is put in series with the tuned circuit's inductor. The pulse amplitude has also increased to 3 volts.

The disturbance on the sinewave is here (about a 9 mV perturbation at 4 ms into the waveform): -

[image]

If the pulse got wider (say 80 ns), the disturbance changes: -

[image]

You should also notice that the rate of climb of the sinewave amplitude has also increased due to more energy in the pulse being fed to the LC circuit. Bigger picture: -

[image]

> *Also , what happens to the back emf at resonance ? and - what happens
> to the back emf when ringing occurs at resonance ?*

When an inductor is used on its own and is open-circuited (whilst conducting current) you get a back-emf. That back-emf is a release of the stored energy over a very short period of time and, unquenched, will lead to a spark. In an LC tuned circuit (parallel for example), the energy transfers to the capacitor in a controlled way and, the rate that which energy transfers first to the capacitor and then back to the inductor (etc.) defines the resonant frequency. Back-emf and resonance are both resulting from energy stored in the inductor.